# Is it possible to specify a buffer access clause in frama-c?

Tags: c, frama-c

Assuming I have the following function:

```
void process_data(uint32_t * data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        foo(data[i]);
    }
}
```

How can I tell Frama-C “this function ensures every access to `data[i]` satisfies condition `i < length`”? As far as I understand, I can place an assertion near every line of code that reads `data`, but is there a better way?

Comment: question for you - is it absolutely guaranteed, that `data` will be non-NULL and point to collection of `uint32_t` ? Maybe an assertion is needed before going into the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, `data` is `\valid` and it points to an array of uint32_t.

Comment: What do you mean by "this function ensures ..."? It seems to me that you want to say "this function requires ..." (otherwise, you have invalid memory accesses), don't you?

Comment: As far as I understand, "requires" means that every buffer passed to function contain `length` elements. What I want to do is prevent invalid memory accesses — so I need to specify a rule meaning "`data` contains `length` elements and every access past `length` is invalid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent invalid memory accesses, you need to check that this function is always called with a `data` pointer from which at least `length` elements can be read. So you need to write a precondition:

```
//@ requires \valid_read (data + (0 .. length-1));
void process_data(uint32_t * data, size_t length) {
```

So if you can ensure that this property is valid, it guarantees that you won't have any invalid memory accesses.

Comment: Perhaps I am too unclear in explaining this, sorry. I want frama-c wp to fail a certain check when `process_data` function can potentially access `data` outside the `length` dimensions. For example, the check should fail if `process_data` contains statement `uint32_t a = data[length + 1]`.

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm afraid the answer depends on your use of Frama-C. E.g, if you want to use WP with `-wp-rte`, Anne's annotation is really what you need: since WP only knows what is written in the requires, any attempt to access an index greater than `length` will result in an Unknown status in the RTE annotation. If instead you use Value and `process_data` is called with a buffer of size greater than `length`, you'll need more specific annotations, which you have to provide yourself (or through a custom script). Feel free to refine your question so that we can provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: This explains it. I thought requires clause only affects value analysis, thank you.